# Django user sessions browser quit not ending session

Tags: python, django, session, django-sessions

I am using the following library
https://github.com/Bouke/django-user-sessions to get the ability to end my session on the fly.

When I am quitting the browser(not closing but ending the browser running task) the user session does not end.

I tried using SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True thinking that the library might leverage it but it doesn't work
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a client-side script using jQuery to guarantee session quit.
See [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/detect-browser-or-tab-closing).